# Prove that $f(x)$ is everywhere finite and everywhere locally unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Consider the following. If $f(x)$ is rational function so that $x=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers such that the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms and $n>0$, then $m$ and $n$ are uniquely determined. Therefore the following function is well-defined:

$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{11} n & x \in \mathbb{Q}, \,\, x=\frac{m}{n} \,\, \text{in lowest terms}, n>0 \\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{array} \right.$$

Prove that this function is everywhere finite and everywhere locally unbounded. 
Hint: Start the second part by defining "locally bounded."

I would appreciate if anyone could define what everywhere finite means. It seems to me that this function is everywhere finite since it only outputs values of $n$ when $n>0$ and $0$ otherwise. We know since $\frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms, then a lot of fractions will repeat.

I then defined a locally bounded function $f(x)$. Locally bounded function $f(x)$ means for any $x$, $\exists$open set $O$ such that $x \in O$ such that $f(O)$ is a bounded set. In other words, for some number $M$, $|f(x)| \leq M \,\, \forall x \in O$.

I tried using the Archimedean Property to show that now function value can be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First approach:

Assume $f$ is bounded in open $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$, then obviously the denominators of all rational numbers in this neighbourhood must be bounded (i.e. $n$ for $x=\frac mn$). This implies that the numerators must also be bounded (i.e. $m$ for $x = \frac mn$), otherwise $\frac mn$ would not lie in $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$ for large values of $m$. But this would mean there are only finitely many rational numbers in that neighbourhood of $a$. This contradiction proves the claim. $\square$

---

### Second approach:

Let's look at the Thomae's functions first:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\frac 1n, \ \ x = \frac mn \\ 0, \ \ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$ You can find a proof at the Internet that the limit of Thomae's function vanish at all points (here is one at [mathcounterexamples](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-continuous-at-all-irrationals-and-discontinuous-at-all-rationals/)). Therefore,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{g(x)}, \ \ x = \frac mn \\ 0, \ \ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$ is unbounded at any point.